# How do you concatenate two wchar_t* together?

Tags: c++

I have a base `wchar_t*` and I'm looking to append another one onto the end.  How do I do it?  I cannot use deprecated functions as I am treating warnings as errors.

Comment: If you mean with "deprecated", the standard functions that Microsoft doesn't like, then don't bother. Do you really want to have vendor lock-in, but still no absolute safety? Just define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ` in the project file, and VC++ will shut up.

Answer (score 23):

Why not use a `std::wstring` in the first place:

```
wchar_t *ws1 = foo(), *ws2 = bar();
std::wstring s(ws1);
s += std::wstring(ws2);
std::wcout << s << std::endl;
```

If needed, `std::wstring::c_str()` gives you access to the result as a `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: or `const wchar_t * concatenation = s.c_str();` depending -- but yes the first thing I'd do is wrap them in a string type.

Answer (score 8):

```
 #include <wchar.h>

 wchar_t *wcsncat(wchar_t *ws1, const wchar_t *ws2, size_t n);
```

The `wcsncat()` function appends no more than the first n characters of the string pointed to by `ws2` to the end of the string pointed to by `ws1`. If a `NULL` character appears in `ws2` before `n` characters, all characters up to the `NULL` character are appended to `ws1`. The first character of `ws2` overwrites the terminating `NULL` character of `ws1`. A `NULL` terminating character is always appended to the result, and if the objects used for copying overlap, the behavior is undefined.

`ws1`

Is the null-terminated destination string.

`ws2`

Is the null-terminated source string.

`n`

Is the number of characters to append.

Comment: It has been declared deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

The most portable way to do this is `wcsncat` as mentioned above, but it sounds like you're committed to the "secure CRT" features of Visual C++ 2005 and later. (Only Microsoft has "deprecated" those functions.) If that's the case, use [`wcsncat_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6w3kbaf(VS.80).aspx), declared in string.h.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `wstrncat/wcsncat` functions is good, but I think the best version of these safe string functions are the 'l' ones created by Open BSD, i.e. `strlcat` and `wstrlcat`. With the 'n' versions, you can end up with a string that doesn't have a null terminator so you can still have security issues. Also certain implementations will zero out the unused space in the buffer which can slow things down a bit.

The wikipedia page has some more information on these functions: [Strlcpy et al.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy). The only problem is these are not in the standard libraries so you have to include the code in your project yourself.

Here's the source to a `wstrlcat` function:

```
/*
 * Appends src to string dst of size siz (unlike strncat, siz is the
 * full size of dst, not space left).  At most siz-1 characters
 * will be copied.  Always NUL terminates (unless siz = siz, truncation occurred.
 */
size_t wstrlcat(wchar_t *dst, const wchar_t *src, size_t siz)
{
        wchar_t *d = dst;
        const wchar_t *s = src;
        size_t n = siz;
        size_t dlen;

        /* Find the end of dst and adjust bytes left but don't go past end */
        while(n-- != 0 && *d != L'\0') {
                d++;
        }

        dlen = d - dst;
        n = siz - dlen;

        if (n == 0) {
                return(dlen + wcslen(s));
        }

        while(*s != L'\0')
        {
                if(n != 1)
                {
                        *d++ = *s;
                        n--;
                }
                s++;
        }

        *d = '\0';
        return(dlen + (s - src));        /* count does not include NUL */
}
```